# Esbuild cjs not working when importing the default of an hybrid module

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs, esbuild

I am building a module with **esbuild**. It uses `euberlog` as a dependency, which is an hybrid module providing both esm and cjs support.

In my code I therefore use:

```js
import logger from 'euberlog';
```

And then I compile it with esbuild:

```js
const shared = {
        platform: 'node',
        entryPoints: ['source/index.ts'],
        bundle: true,
        minify: true,
        treeShaking: true,
        sourcemap: true
    };

    build({
        ...shared,
        outfile: 'bundled/lib/commonjs/index.js',
        format: 'cjs',
        external: getExternalDependencies()
    });
```

It is actually built both for esm and cjs.
The problem is that if I import the cjs module somewhere, I have the error:

```
TypeError: i.default.info is not a function
```

and then if I patch the code and print `i`, I see that the result is:

```
{ default: { Logger: [Getter], default: [Getter] }, Logger: [Getter] }
```

It seems like that esbuild translates the first import (`import logger from 'euberlog'`) as `import * as logger from 'euberlog'`, but this does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be hitting an issue with ESM/CJS interoperation, which is described in [this lengthy article in TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/appendices/esm-cjs-interop.html), in [this comment by esbuild’s Evan](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1719#issuecomment-953470495), and in [esbuild docs about `default` export](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#default-interop).

- First, I recommend double-checking your `tsconfig.json` per that TS docs article. After all, esbuild does use it too.
- You may want to check if you are hitting esbuild-specific behavior. Per the third link above you can see that even `{ "type": "module" }` in your `package.json` may affect how default exports are treated.